# trying to implement an A* algorithm after hours of trying I thought I'd ask for someone to review my code

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

I've been trying to implement an A* algorithm in a tower defense style game and after hours of trying I thought I'd ask for some insight in my logic flaws.
I've been trying to create it via http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/ & https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602061/1550619 
But and infinite problem occurs when trying to generate the successors/neighbors to an AStarNode(I think) - First time implementing A* and still learning.

```
private ArrayList<AStarNode> aStaring(Object o, AStarNode start, AStarNode goal) {
    ArrayList<AStarNode> closed = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList<AStarNode> open = new ArrayList();

    start.g = 0;
    start.h = estimateDistance(start, goal);
    start.f = 0;

    open.add(start);

    while(!open.isEmpty()){
        AStarNode q = null;

        for(AStarNode asn : open){
            if(q == null || asn.f < q.f){
                q = asn;
            }
        }

        open.remove(q);
        closed.add(q);
        for(AStarNode succesor : q.generateSuccesors()){
            if(closed.contains(succesor)){
                System.out.println("Closed contained succesor");
                //TODO Check if walkable 
            }else{
                if(!open.contains(succesor)){
                    succesor.g = q.g+1;
                    succesor.h = estimateDistance(succesor, goal);
                    succesor.f = succesor.g + succesor.h;
                    succesor.parent = q;
                    open.add(succesor);
                }else{
                    float nextG = q.g + succesor.cost;
                    if(nextG < succesor.g){
                        open.remove(succesor);
                        closed.add(succesor);
                    }
                }
                if(succesor.x == goal.x && succesor.y == goal.y){ //path found
                    System.out.println("hurray");
                    return reconstructPath(succesor);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public class AStarNode {

private MapDimension md = new MapDimension();
public AStarNode parent;
public int x,y;
public int f,g,h;
public int cost = 1;

public AStarNode(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

//Looking up 4 neighbors and adding to node;
public ArrayList<AStarNode> generateSuccesors(){
    ArrayList<AStarNode> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    if(x+1 < md.getWidth()){
        AStarNode temp = new AStarNode(x+1,y);
        temp.parent = this;
        neighbors.add(temp);
    }
    if(x-1 > 0){
        AStarNode temp = new AStarNode(x-1,y);
        temp.parent = this;
        neighbors.add(temp);
    }
    if(y+1 < md.getHeight()){
        AStarNode temp = new AStarNode(x,y+1);
        temp.parent = this;
        neighbors.add(temp);
    }
    if(y-1 > 0){
        AStarNode temp = new AStarNode(x,y-1);
        temp.parent = this;
        neighbors.add(temp);
    }
    return neighbors;
}
}
```

Map:

```
public static final int[][] MAP = {
    {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2},
    {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2},
    {2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    {2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1},
    {2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1},
    {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2},
    {2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2},
    {0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2},
};
```

Any pointers towards the right direction would be fantastic :]

Comment: At first glance, you don't seem to have anything in place that will prevent you from going from a node `x` to `y` then back to `x` then back to `y` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you run generateSuccessors, you create 4 (or less) NEW instances of AStarNode objects. This is not a problem per se, but AStarNode does not define hashCode and equals. So two nodes with the same coordinates are not considered equals, so `closed.contains(successor)` will NEVER return true.

Implement hashCode and equals on AStarNode (or get your IDE to do it for you). Something as simple as:

```
public int hashCode(){
   return x*y;
}

public boolean equals(Object o){
  if (o instanceof AStarNode){
    return x==((AStarNode)o).x && y==((AStarNode)o).y;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Argh, my head must be tired! Thanks a lot.